# Network Printer Disappears After Logout

Tags: networking, vpn, printer, network-printer

I have a VPN server at home and a client at shop. The client has an attached USB printer. I have assigned the client a static ip on vpn. Now, I have Printer sharing on (on client). I opened the control Panel on the server and added a network printer with local IP of the client. It is successfully added and printer works absolutely fine. But as soon as I log out and re-login it magically disappears. I have to re-add the printer manually. What is the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: Maybe the User on the V.P.N. Server is not an Administrator. Try again with an Administrator User Account.

Comment: Nope all users are administrators.